# Hamburger menu is not opening

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, navigation

When I mininimize my viewport view, the navigation menu should be hidden in the hamburger mobile button. But when I press it it doesn't open.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbemtom0/2/#&togetherjs=hG4m0jSANh

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-hamburger"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#collapsemenu"
    >

 <div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsemenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
</ul> </div>
```

Comment: Try calling `jquery.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: I have a space in the close of comment  `<!-- Import jquery 3.3.1 slim min-- >` script does not load it.  it must be `<!-- Import jquery 3.3.1 slim min-->` before the calling `jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the JS files are loaded in the wrong order. jQuery is needed for the bootstrap JS to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have links Jquery and Bootstrap js in this order.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```